# How to import large .xlsx file to an oracle sql table [SQL Import Data]

Tags: import, oracle-sqldeveloper, xlsx, xls

i have a .xlsx file containing 1M+ rows and 50 columns.

file size is ~300,000 KB.

when i try to 'Import Data' in oracle sql developer, error shows java heap space.

i have added: `AddVMOption -Xmx4096M` in sqldeveloper.conf file and tried to save .xlsx as .xls but same error occurs.

Comment: A file that big...it's even bigger actually, xlsx is an archive of xml files. If it were mez I would save your file as CSV, then sqldev will rip right through it.

Comment: And if you have an Oracle Client, I'd have sqldev setup a sqlldr scenario, it'll load much faster.